# Recreate the sphere in TeX.SX logo

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, asymptote, metapost, pst-solides3d

I'm trying to recreate this

[image] [image: quack]

But looking in [this Meta question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3989/tex-sx-background-to-be-used-in-a-document) the only code provided doesn't give that output

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document} 

\psset{viewpoint=50 20 10 rtp2xyz,Decran=50}
\psset{unit=0.75}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
\psSolid[object=sphere,r=4,action=draw*,ngrid=9 9,resolution=720]%
\defFunction[algebraic]{helicespherique}(t)%
  {4*cos(10*t)*cos(t)}%
  {4*sin(10*t)*cos(t)}%
  {4*sin(t)}
\psSolid[object=courbe,linecolor=blue,
        resolution=720,range=pi -2 div pi 2 div,
       function=helicespherique,r=0.05]
%\gridIIID[Zmin=-4,Zmax=4](-4,4)(-4,4)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But I know nothing about PSTricks

## How can I reproduce the sphere in the backround of this site?

I'm looking for code (in TikZ, MetaPost, Asymptote or PStricks) to reproduce the image. An important thing is that what's *behind* the ball should be in another layer (thinner or gray). Like the image from this site.

In any case, this is what I ended up with a few changes from the code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document} 

\psset{viewpoint=50 20 40 rtp2xyz,Decran=50}
\psset{unit=0.75}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
\psSolid[object=sphere,r=4,fillcolor=white,ngrid=14 14,resolution=720,linewidth=.1pt,linecolor=gray]%
\defFunction[algebraic]{helicespherique}(t)%
  {4*cos(2*t)*cos(t)}%
  {4*sin(2*t)*cos(t)}%
  {4*sin(t)}
\psSolid[object=courbe,linecolor=black,
        resolution=720,range=pi -2 div pi 2 div,
       function=helicespherique,r=0.0001]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Look](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iAIVp.png).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The (original) image was created using [ePiX](http://mathcs.holycross.edu/%7Eahwang/epix/ePiX.html#Source) (available from [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/epix)). The source [`sphere.xp`](http://mathcs.holycross.edu/%7Eahwang/epix/images/gallery-1.2/sphere.xp) can be compiled using

```bash
elaps <options> sphere.xp
```

to [produce](http://mathcs.holycross.edu/%7Eahwang/epix/images/gallery-1.2/sphere.pdf)

[image]

#### [`sphere.xp`](http://mathcs.holycross.edu/%7Eahwang/epix/images/gallery-1.2/sphere.xp):

```cpp
/* -*-ePiX-*- */
#include "epix.h"
using namespace ePiX;

const double k(2*M_PI/(360*sqrt(3))); // assume "degrees" mode

double exp_cos(double t) { return exp(k*t)*Cos(t); }
double exp_sin(double t) { return exp(k*t)*Sin(t); }
double minus_exp_cos(double t) { return -exp_cos(t); }
double minus_exp_sin(double t) { return -exp_sin(t); }

int main()
{
  picture(P(-1,-1), P(1,1), "2.5 x 2.5in");

  begin();
  degrees(); // set angle units
  camera.at(P(1, 2.5, 3));

  sphere(); // draw unit sphere's horizon

  pen(Blue(1.6)); // hidden portions of loxodromes
  backplot_N(exp_cos, exp_sin, -540, 540, 180);
  backplot_N(minus_exp_cos, minus_exp_sin, -540, 540, 180);

  pen(Red(1.6));
  backplot_N(exp_sin, minus_exp_cos, -540, 540, 180);
  backplot_N(minus_exp_sin, exp_cos, -540, 540, 180);

  pen(Black(0.3)); // coordinate grid

  for (int i=0; i<=12; ++i) {
    latitude(90-15*i, 0, 360);
    longitude(30*i, 0, 360);
  }

  bold(Blue()); // visible portions of loxodromes
  frontplot_N(exp_cos, exp_sin, -540, 540, 360);
  frontplot_N(minus_exp_cos, minus_exp_sin, -540, 540, 360);

  pen(Red());
  frontplot_N(exp_sin, minus_exp_cos, -540, 540, 360);
  frontplot_N(minus_exp_sin, exp_cos, -540, 540, 360);

  end();
}
```

Possible outputs:

- [LaTeX's `picture` environment](http://pastebin.com/CAL6q0VJ); `elaps sphere.xp`
- [PSTricks](http://pastebin.com/8C4SgejN); `elaps --pst sphere.xp`
- [TikZ](http://pastebin.com/yVxYCerp); `elaps --tikz sphere.xp`

Comment: I was going to accept this answer. But may be if the question is not marked as answered more people propose other solutions with other programs? I will wait a few days and then accept it (because this is *the* answer). In any case, you could post this [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3989/tex-sx-background-to-be-used-in-a-document) in the Meta post.

Comment: @Manuel Herbert also did this via PSTricks which is not so difficult for him too. But I can't find the answer. This is not how he did it .

Answer (score 7):

## Minimal Working Solution

```
\documentclass[pstricks,margin=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\psset{viewpoint=50 70 50 rtp2xyz,Decran=50,linewidth=0.5\pslinewidth}

\defFunction[algebraic]{helicespherique}(t)
        {0.5*cos(10*t)*cos(t)}
        {0.5*sin(10*t)*cos(t)}
        {0.5*sin(t)}    

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture*}(-0.5,-0.5)(0.5,0.5)
    \psSolid
    [
        object=sphere,
        fillcolor=gray,
        opacity=.25,
        strokeopacity=.25,
        ngrid=30 30,
        r=0.5,
        grid=false,
    ]
    \psSolid
    [
        object=courbe,
        linewidth=0.05pt,
        range=pi -.5 mul 0.5 pi mul,
        function=helicespherique,
        r=0.005,
        grid=false,
    ]
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Feel free to edit as much as you want.

Comment: I think it needs more than one spiral with different phases.

Comment: This is basically like the original one but rotated the point of view. +1 But I was looking for more aesthetic, with more spirals, similar to the one in the background of the page.

Answer (score 6):

The package pst-rubans draws a spiral ribbon on objects (cylinder, cone, torus, paraboloid, sphere).

[pst-rubans – Draw three-dimensional ribbons](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-rubans)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-rubans}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
\psframe*(-5,-5)(5,5)
\psset{viewpoint=50 20 40,Decran=50,resolution=720,lightsrc=viewpoint}
\psSphericalSpiral[incolor=yellow!20,R=4,fillcolor=orange,grid,dPHI=8]
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document} 

\psset{viewpoint=50 20 40 rtp2xyz,Decran=50,unit=0.75}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
    \psSolid[object=sphere,r=4,ngrid=20 20,linewidth=.1pt,linecolor=black!10,
      action=draw]% don't use hidden lines
    \defFunction[algebraic]{helix}(t)%
        {4*cos(3*t)*cos(t)}%
        {4*sin(3*t)*cos(t)}%
        {4*sin(t)}
    \psSolid[object=courbe,linecolor=black,range=-0.33 1.57,
            function=helix,r=0.02]
    \psSolid[object=courbe,linecolor=black!30,range=-1.57 -0.33,
    function=helix,r=0.02]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Using the code with epix, please find a (non optimized) Asymptote version.

```
size(10cm);
import three;
import graph3;
import math;
import solids;
settings.render=0; 
settings.prc=false; // on se restreint à une vue 2d


currentprojection=orthographic(1,2.5,3);

real  k=2*pi/(360*sqrt(3));

real  exp_cos(real t) { return exp(k*t)*Cos(t); }
real  exp_sin(real t) { return exp(k*t)*Sin(t); }
real minus_exp_cos(real t) { return -exp_cos(t); }
real minus_exp_sin(real t) { return -exp_sin(t); }

triple f1(real t)
{
  real ss;
  triple ff;
  ss=exp_cos(t)^2+exp_sin(t)^2+1;
  ff=(2*exp_cos(t)/ss,2*exp_sin(t)/ss,(ss-2)/ss);
  return ff;
}


triple f2(real t)
{
  real ss;
  triple ff;
  ss=minus_exp_cos(t)^2+minus_exp_sin(t)^2+1;
  ff=(2*minus_exp_cos(t)/ss,2*minus_exp_sin(t)/ss,(ss-2)/ss);
  return ff;
}

triple f3(real t)
{
  real ss;
  triple ff;
  ss=exp_sin(t)^2+minus_exp_cos(t)^2+1;
  ff=(2*exp_sin(t)/ss,2*minus_exp_cos(t)/ss,(ss-2)/ss);
  return ff;
}


triple f4(real t)
{
  real ss;
  triple ff;
  ss=minus_exp_sin(t)^2+exp_cos(t)^2+1;
  ff=(2*minus_exp_sin(t)/ss,2*exp_cos(t)/ss,(ss-2)/ss);
  return ff;
}


revolution r=sphere(O,1);
draw(r,9,gray,longitudinalpen=nullpen,backpen=nullpen);
draw(r.silhouette());


for(int k=-2; k<5;++k) 
  draw(rotate(k*30,(0,0,1))*rotate(-90,(1,0,0))*r,1,gray,
       longitudinalpen=nullpen,backpen=nullpen);
int nbpts=280;
real step=1080/nbpts;


draw(graph(f1,-540,540,280,Spline),blue+gray);
draw(graph(f2,-540,540,280,Spline),blue+gray);
draw(graph(f3,-540,540,280,Spline),red+gray);
draw(graph(f4,-540,540,280,Spline),red+gray);


triple[] P1=new triple[nbpts];
triple[] P2=new triple[nbpts];
triple[] P3=new triple[nbpts];
triple[] P4=new triple[nbpts];

for(int i=0; i < nbpts; ++i) {
  real t=-540+i*step;
  P1[i]=f1(t);
  P2[i]=f2(t);
  P3[i]=f3(t);
  P4[i]=f4(t);

}

bool[] front1=new bool[nbpts];
bool[] front2=new bool[nbpts];
bool[] front3=new bool[nbpts];
bool[] front4=new bool[nbpts];


for(int i=0; i < nbpts; ++i) {
  front1[i]=dot(P1[i],currentprojection.camera) > 0;
  front2[i]=dot(P2[i],currentprojection.camera) > 0;
  front3[i]=dot(P3[i],currentprojection.camera) > 0;
  front4[i]=dot(P4[i],currentprojection.camera) > 0;
}
draw(segment(P1,front1,operator ..),blue+1bp);
draw(segment(P2,front2,operator ..),blue+1bp);
draw(segment(P3,front3,operator ..),red+1bp);
draw(segment(P4,front4,operator ..),red+1bp);
```

And the result.

[image]