# pstricks, psSolid and pstODE

Tags: pstricks

Using `\psSolid` I can create nice pictures of a graph
of a function, say f(x,y)=x*x-y*y.

Using

> `\pstODE[algebraic,algebraicOutputFormat]{solution}{ "x" |"y" | f("x","y") }{...`

I can solve an (high-dimensional) ODE and obtain a three-dimensional
"curve" on the graph of f .

With `listplotThreeD{solution}` I can visualize this 3D-curve on the graph.

However, this curve will in general not lie on the graph created by
`\psSolid`. For instance the output of `ListplotThreeD` will not change
when changing the viewpoint in `\psSolid`.

Is there a way around that?

Comment: In [one](http://manuel.luque.perso.neuf.fr/orbites-dans-paraboloid/orbites-dans-paraboloid.tex) of his numerous [examples](http://pstricks.blogspot.de), M. Luque defines the command `\listplotIIID` as an equivalent to the standard `\listplotThreeD` command, but compatible with the `pst-solides3d` package.

Answer (score 3):

`pst-solides3d` and  `pst-3dplot` can be used together but the macros use a different coordinate system. You can define an on `\listplotIIID` as mentioned by Alexander as:

```
\makeatletter
\def\listplotIIID{\def\pst@par{}\pst@object{listplotIIID}}
\def\listplotIIID@i#1{%
\@nameuse{beginplot@\psplotstyle}%
\addto@pscode{%
   /viewpointXYZ {\pst@solides@viewpoint} def
   /Decran \pst@solides@Decran\space def % distance de l'ecran
    viewpointXYZ /ZpointVue ED /YpointVue ED /XpointVue ED
  /THETA {YpointVue XpointVue atan} bind def
  /PHI   {ZpointVue XpointVue dup mul YpointVue dup mul add sqrt atan} bind def
  /Dobs  {XpointVue dup mul YpointVue dup mul add ZpointVue dup mul add sqrt} bind def
  XpointVue YpointVue ZpointVue /viewpoint defpoint3d
    /XYZ [#1] def
  /@tabXYZ [
    0 3 XYZ length 3 sub {/i exch def
     XYZ i get
     XYZ i 1 add get
     XYZ i 2 add get
     3dto2d
     \pst@number\psunit mul exch
     \pst@number\psunit mul exch
    }  for
    ] bind def
 [ @tabXYZ aload pop
    }%
\@nameuse{endplot@\psplotstyle}}%
\makeatother
```

The data must be a file with 3d records like

```
1 2 3
4 5 1
2.1 0 1.1
...
```

The current viewport setting of `pst-solides3d` is valid.

Comment: Could you please have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251734/recreate-the-sphere-in-tex-sx-logo . I remember it was one of your answers but I can't find it.